# Characters in <style> converted to unicode HTML Entity in cross-origin requests

Tags: html, reactjs, cross-domain, next.js, css-in-js

I have a NextJS application that uses react-jss.

In my CSS I have rule that targets `'& .working[style="display: block;"] ': {...}`

I can build, run, and see this working fine when I hit the page on the same domain the server is running on, and I have a number of individual `<style>` tags that look like:

```html
<style data-jss="" data-meta="Themed">...</style>
<style data-jss="" data-meta="Themed">...</style>
...
```

When I access that same page served from another domain, however, (or with Postman) I see that the the rule in question has had the `"` character replaced with `&quot;` so that it looks like `.working[style=&quot;display: block;&quot;]` (this is not limited to `"` - a `>` later in that rule is replaced with `&gt;`). The styles are also all served under a single `<style>` tag:

```html
<style id="server-side-styles">...</styles>
```

The application is not doing anything fancy, the styles are added in `_document.js` as shown here: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/canary/examples/with-react-jss/pages/_document.js

I don't believe this is a NextJS or react-jss problem, as when I inspect the stringified registry on the server (when making the request via Postman) I still see the style as it is originally written, without the character conversion.

**Is there something related to CORS or cross-origin requests that would cause `"` to be replaced with `&quot;` in this manner? If yes, how can I prevent this? If no, am I missing something obvious?**

Comment: @sideshowbarker thinking through your removal of the cors tag I'm assuming it was because this issue is also encountered with Postman? That was not something I had considered, and since I was asking explicitly if it could be related to CORS, at least a comment to that affect would have been helpful. Definitely something obvious I missed...

Comment: In general given a particular problem, the way you can know whether it’s related to CORS is to look in devtools console and see if the browser has logged any messages there which explicitly mention CORS. If the browser hasn’t logged any messages in the console that explicitly mention CORS. And as far as the particular issue described in the question, there’s nothing in the CORS protocol nor in browser behavior related to CORS which would cause the behavior described in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the example you linked, on this line:

```
<style id="server-side-styles">{registry.toString()}</style>
```

you need to use React's [`dangerouslySetInnerHTML`](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml) convention otherwise the string returned there is going to get escaped, like you're seeing.

Per the example link, that would have `_document.js` looking like:

```
import Document from 'next/document'
import { SheetsRegistry, JssProvider, createGenerateId } from 'react-jss'

export default class JssDocument extends Document {
  static async getInitialProps(ctx) {
    const registry = new SheetsRegistry()
    const generateId = createGenerateId()
    const originalRenderPage = ctx.renderPage
    ctx.renderPage = () =>
      originalRenderPage({
        enhanceApp: (App) => (props) => (
          <JssProvider registry={registry} generateId={generateId}>
            <App {...props} />
          </JssProvider>
        ),
      })

    const initialProps = await Document.getInitialProps(ctx)
    const rawStyles = {
      __html: registry.toString(),
    }

    return {
      ...initialProps,
      styles: (
        <>
          {initialProps.styles}
          <style id="server-side-styles" dangerouslySetInnerHTML={rawStyles} />
        </>
      ),
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This was it, thanks. I'll add an edit with some code once the edit queue is no longer full.